# Android Listview dialog doesn't disapear after choosing an item

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I've tried to create a list view dialog to display a list of choose. My code is shown below:

```
        LayoutInflater factory=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View stuckLevelDialogView=factory.inflate(R.layout.report_stuck_dialog, null);

    final ListView stuckLevelListViewForDialog=(ListView)stuckLevelDialogView.findViewById(R.id.report_stuck_dialog_listview);
    final String[] stuckLevelList=new String[]{"1 - You can move freely","2 - You have to be aware of your movement","3 - You can move slowly","4 - There is a traffic jam","5 - There is a serious traffic jam"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForDialog=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stuckLevelList);
    stuckLevelListViewForDialog.setAdapter(adapterForDialog);

    final AlertDialog.Builder stuckLevelDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    stuckLevelDialog.setTitle("What stuck level is this point?");
    stuckLevelDialog.setView(stuckLevelDialogView);
    stuckLevelDialog.show();
```

However, when I choose an option, the onItemClick is executed, but the listview dialog doesn't disappear, I have to press back button manually. I've tried to debug the code for a whole day, but it has not been solved yet. Please help me. Thank in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `dismiss()` the dialog in your `onItemClick` listener as below:

> ```
>     stuckLevelListViewForDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p_arg0, View p_arg1,
>                 int p_arg2, long p_arg3) {
>         stuckLevelDialog.dismiss();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Small correction,  `AlertDialog dialog=stuckLevelDialog.show()`  and then in your onItemClick  `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: @Pragnani and Grishu: Thank you, with your correction, I've finally solved my problem!

Comment: Always grateful to help @NgoAnhTuan-HEDSPI ... :)

Comment: @GrIsHu, why do you need to call `dismiss` explicitly here whereas you do not need it when an array instead of a listview is used with `stuckLevelDialog.setItems(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use stuckLevelDialog.dismiss; at the end of onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `setSingleChoiceItems` in your alert dialog box with your items list, which will show a list with a radio buttons. If you want to add buttons you can else once user select any items you can `dismiss` the `dialog`.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setSingleChoiceItems(array, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // here you can do your functionality and can dismiss dialog as well
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })        
    .show();
```

Comment: Yes, I know about setSingleChoiceItems with radio buttons, but is it possible to create a dialog with the simple list like that? By the way, the AlertDialog.Builder object doesn't come with dismiss method.

Comment: @NgoAnhTuan-HEDSPI Check comment below Girishu's answer